# Correctly parsing through a JSON array with multiple objects using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am able to print out the response. However I am unable to loop through the array and initialise it. This is how I am requesting the data:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in

    print(response.value!)

    guard let data = response.data else { return }
    let json = JSON(data: data)

    for r in json.arrayValue {
        let person = Person(json: r)
    }
}
```

I have added breakpoints but I am unable to understand as to why the loop does not happen?

**Update:**

`response.value!` example:

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "object_count": 1,
    "page_number": 1
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "id": "818060297",
      "quantity": 1,
      "profile": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "company": "Apple",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "john_doe@testmail.com",
        "job_title": "CEO"
      },
      "status": "Attending"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update 2**

Here is my AttendeesProfile class:

```
class AttendeesProfile {

    var name: String?

    init(json: JSON) {
        self.name = json["name"].stringValue
    }

}
```

Now I am not sure how to get the Attendee class to work properly:

```
class Attendees {

    var attendees = [String]()
    var attendeesProfile: AttendeesProfile!

    init(json: JSON) {
        // Something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing what the data you are passing in here is (or the structure of the JSON) it will be quite difficult to help you with specific answers that will help you resolve your issue.

Comment: How will I show you the response as it it contains massive data.

Comment: The structure would help, so is it a top level object containing many children, and do those children contain children, etc? Can you `po json.arrayValue.count` in lldb to see if there are any entries?

Comment: @AdamFallon please see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `guard` statement stopping your code flow before you loop through your array : `guard let data = response.data else { return }`

With this line, you are saying if data has something then the code flow can continue. If not, please stop it and return. So, you never reach your loop statement.

**Are you sure that your `response.data` has something and is different from nil ?** Your `print(response.value!)` shows something ?

Comment: When I run a breakpoint after the `guard let` it reaches the next line. And if I print response.data I get `▿ Optional<Data>
  ▿ some : 56757 bytes
    - count : 56757
    ▿ pointer : 0x00007fed5f07e200
      - pointerValue : 140657478328832`

Comment: Can you try to print your json constant ?

Comment: I get this `expression produced error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffff8).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
`

Comment: Oh bad error ! And if your print your constant data ? Maybe your JSON initializer has a problem and don't initialize your json constant. So, your json constant is empty and your loop has no reason to loop.

Comment: When I print out json in the console after the guard let I get the entire json array. It looks as though it is returning a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast your response data. You can not walk on an unknown array
I suggest you to use ObjectMapper library. It can parse your data to your willing model and if received data is nil or is not your wanted model you can find out easily. Do not forget to print response.data to ensure what data exactly is.
https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

Comment: Sorry, I have never used this framework. Is it not possible to achieve it with just  SwiftyJSON?If not, could you demonstrate how I could use this with my problem?

Comment: are you sure your response is not empty and is in the right way?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly how I have demonstrated. `response.data = 56757 bytes`

Comment: let me know json and a json.arrayValue when you print them

Comment: try String(data: response.data! , encoding: .utf8)

Comment: It gives me the array but in a different format `..Optional("{\"pagination\": {\"object_count\": 41, \"page_number\": 1,...`

Comment: see this not what you mentioned before. It has some field that you do not parse

Comment: Ahh I see, apologies I'm still new to parsing JSON. Where would go next?

Comment: I guess your API URL is wrong. you are getting data from the wrong API or update your Person model

Comment: I am unable to go into just the attendees array as the this is only available url. What would the Person model look like if this is the case?

Comment: I don`t know man it`s your app. Try to update your model with received data model

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a couple of structs conforming to `Decodable`, which among other things would give you the benefit of not relying on SwiftyJSON for your code to work.

Going off from the JSON data that you have provided, consider the following three simple structs:

```
struct AttendeeArray: Decodable {
   let attendees: [Attendee]
}

struct Attendee: Decodable {
   let status: String
   let profile: AttendeeProfile
}

struct AttendeeProfile: Decodable {
   let name: String
   let age: Int
}
```

Each struct simply contains the variables that you have defined in your JSON object.

Using the `JSONDecoder` you will now be able to decode your JSON data as simple as calling:

```
do { 
   let array = try JSONDecoder().decode(AttendeeArray.self, from: data)
   // do whatever with your attendees array
} catch {
   // handle error if parsing fails
   print(error)
}
```

I created a simple Playground where you can test this by adding the code bolow along with the `Decodable` structs above:

```
import Foundation

func decodeAttendees(json: String) -> AttendeeArray? {
   guard let data = json.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
   do {
       return try JSONDecoder().decode(AttendeeArray.self, from: data)
   } catch {
       print("Error: \(error)")
       return nil
   }
}

let json = """
{
   "attendees": [
       {
           "status": "attending",
           "profile": {
               "name": "Joe",
               "age": 22
           }
       },
       {
           "status": "not attending",
           "profile": {
               "name": "Bob",
               "age": 44
           }
       }
   ],
   "servlet": {
       "servlet-name": "cofaxCDS",
       "servlet-class": "org.cofax.cds.CDSServlet"
   }
}
"""

let arr = decodeAttendees(json: json)
arr?.attendees[0].profile.name //"Joe"
arr?.attendees[1].status //"not attending"
```

Now, for your current Alamofire completion handler, I'm guessing that it would be as simple to modify it to be something along the lines of:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding:   URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
   guard let data = response.data else { return //remember to error if data is nil }
   do {
      let array = JSONDecoder().decode(AttendeesArray.self, from: data)
      //update your UI to show the array, or pass it on to a completion hanldler
   } catch {
      //handle errors
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Are you suggesting that with SwiftyJSON there comes a limitation when parsing through a JSON array with multiple objects? In the meantime I will have an attempt on your suggestion and see what I can do. I just feel as though that I am using different methods to parse JSON data in my app already. Or is this normal?

Comment: SwiftyJSON is definetly a great framework, which provides a lot of flexibility. I also use it myself. However, I think that you should at least know of the alternatives. Now that Apple has added the `Codable` protocols, handling JSON encoding/decoding of native objects has become a lot easier than previously.